# How do I know what is being mapped and what is being reduced in a SQL query?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I read the MapReduce wiki page, and I don't think I fully understand. I understand that the queries are split into a map step and a reduce step. So to take advantage of this, we should use `GROUP BY`s more and move the work from the map step to the reduce step. I'm not really sure how does this work. It seems so magical. I want to know a set of guidelines for writing a SQL query to take advantage of the MapReduce.

How do I know which clauses are in the map step or reduce step? What is the theory behind it? I want to understand the theory and its inner workings, so that I can write better queries.

Answer (score 0):

Map function is `data preparation stage` ,where Mapper can `prepare and filter` the data so that It can pass the same as input to `reducer function`.
Reducer takes the input from Mapper and tries to reduce the data if specified in the query.
for example reducer will caliculate the aggregates like `count,max,min of a column` from the data given by mapper.
For example I you have requirement for `finding word count for the words not in set a,an and the`.

```
not filtering is done by mapper.

counting is done by by reducer.
```

As per my understanding Three things in Hive query will lead to reducer function.

```
1.group by

2.join

3.multi row function
```

Most of the rest will lead to Mapper function.

Comment: What's a multi row function? Is that the same as an aggregate function?

Answer (score 0):

Hive will try to optimize the number of map/reduces it does (and the work between map and reduce) as much as it can based on the query. If you want to control the map/reduce behavior you can write your own map/reduces in java, the whole point of Hive is that it will let you use a familiar syntax (SQL) to express the results you want to get and it would create an efficient map/reduce sequence to get that result

For performance reasons you probably want to get as much work as possible in the map phase - since there are usually more mappers than reducers and you don't need to move data around. Note that sometime aggregate functions can be  partially executed on the map side with a combiner (though I think Hive handles this differently) 
from [Hive site](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-groupby.html):

> Map-side Aggregation for Group By
>
> hive.map.aggr controls how we do aggregations. The default is false.
>   If it is set to true, Hive will do the first-level aggregation
>   directly in the map task. This usually provides better efficiency, but
>   may require more memory to run successfully.
>
> set hive.map.aggr=true; 
>     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2